# Cannot enable or find option to enable GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

i just started using blender recently and wanted to render an animation made with my gpu cos it was taking ages with the cpu. I went to user prefrences to enable the gpu but the cuda option wasnt there for me to click.(i have a Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 gpu if that matters) also im using cycles [image]

Comment: Integrated graphics cards such as the Intel HD Graphics 3000 are not supported for GPU rendering. This is true for all Blender versions, e.g. [2.79](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#introduction) and [2.9x](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#introduction).

Comment: damn well thanks for letting me know. What graphics card would u reccomend